# Ionic Cordova android build failed

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an error while building the android part of my project.

```
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * What went wrong:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : > Failed to install the following SDK components:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  [Android SDK Platform 26]
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  The SDK directory (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidSDK\25) is not writeable,
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  please update the directory permissions.
```

I have already installed the **Android SDK Platform 26** but on a different location. *(C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk)*

But the cordova accessing a different directory *(C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidSDK\25)*

I'm thinking, how could I change the SDK path of the Ionic? Or how could I give permission to Ionic to write on a specific folder? Thanks!

PS: System Information

```
Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.5.7
Cordova-Android: 6.2.3
Cordova: 8.0.0
Gradle: 4.6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the environment variable ANDROID_HOME to the right directory in your terminal

```
    set ANDROID_HOME=C:\<installation location>\
    set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
```